# Angular and Typescript: Instantiate complex objects

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript

I'm working with Angular and I came across a difficulty with a TypeScript language. I'm not sure about the TypeScript syntax.

I don't understand why I create an object like this:

```
export class MyClass {

  isTrue: boolean;

  complexObject: {
    minValue: number;
    stringValue: string;
  };

  MyClassString: string;
  MyClassString2: string;
  MyClassString3: string;

}
```

And I create an MyClass array like this:

```
export const MYCLASS: MyClass[] = [
{ 
  isTrue: false,
  complexObject: {
    minValue: 7,
    stringValue: "hello"
  },
  MyClassString: "one",
  MyClassString2: "two",
  MyClassString3: "three"
}];
```

The Angular compiler makes an error even if there are no syntax errors in this code.

If I remove "complexObject" everything works correctly.
If I create instances only with primitive types, there are no mistakes.
How do I create complex objects and initialize them into an array without compilation errors?

Can I instantiate objects with this syntax only if they have primitive types?

The error is: Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'complexObject' does not exist in type 'MyClass'

Comment: MyClass is a class, but you're trying to use it as a type.

Comment: @claudioz If I take your code and plop it into the [TS playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/) I get no error. Some old versions of TS have bugs. If you are using an old version, you should upgrade. Otherwise, you need to add details to your question (by *editing* it, not by adding comments under it) so that people can reproduce the real issue you are having.

Answer (score 0):

I think that will be better if you declare your class in this way:

```
export class ComplexType {
    minValue: number;
    stringValue: string;
}

export class MyClass {

  isTrue: boolean;

  complexObject: ComplexType;

  myClassString: string;
  myClassString2: string;
  myClassString3: string;

}
```

Comment: The result doesn't change after the assignments

Comment: @claudioz could you edit your post and show error message, which you got?

Comment: The error is: Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'complexObject' does not exist in type 'MyClass'

Answer (score -1):

You can define const like below

```
export const MYCLASS:Array<MyClass>=[
  {
  },
  {
  }
]
```

Comment: Not a useful answer as the code he gave will compile without errors so whatever error he's getting (and he left us to guess what it might be) is probably due to something in other code not posted.

Comment: The error is:
Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'complexObject' does not exist in type 'MyClass'